# Crawl can't find ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, crawl

I have upgraded my search admin database and it just can't seem to find the necessary certificate even though I made a crawl rule for it

The error goes like this every time I crawl:

> Cannot find or access the client certificate specified for crawling this site.

- Ssl works normally for SharePoint browsing
- Certificate is added to trust in SharePoint Central admin

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set permission for crawl account on certificate:

```
WinHttpCertCfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s 'certificatename'  -a crawlaccount
```

Comment: got rid of error, but a New one now is: Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository